# How to query custom AEM metadata in Solr

Tags: solr, aem

I've done Solr integration with Remote solr server and all the indexes were created, everything is fine.

Problem: I am not getting search result when I tried with OOTB metadata (dc:title) images though DAM Console search and asset viewer. It works only when I search on the node name GeoCube_Datasheet.pdf (Node name of type dam:Asset) . After I added a custom metadata for an Asset under jcr:content/metadata node, lets say dam:custom of type String, after I added another node under oak:index with below properties :

```
   jcr:primaryType=oak:QueryIndexDefinition, reindex=true ( type Boolean) ,
      propertyNames=dam:custom (type Name[]), type = property (type String).
```

After I modified schema.xml of Solr as :

```
   <field name="dam:custom" type="matchall" />
```

After doing above configuration I can see the index is created in Solr Admin console. Solr admin console returns json output.

```
     "path_exact":  "/content/dam/geometrixx/portraits/scott_reynolds.jpg/
       jcr:content/metadata", "jcr:primaryType": [ "nt:unstructured" ],

      "dam:custom": [ "helloworld" ],
```

But When I do fulltext search in DAM console/ Asset viewer then Querybuilder does not return anything. But When I use default search engine (Lucene) then it returns records based on custom metadata.

For testing purpose when I executed this somehost:port/bin/querybuilder.json?fulltext=helloworld&type=dam:Asset then it does not return anything but it returns resukt when I executed somehost:port/bin/querybuilder.json?fulltext=helloworld&type=nt:unstructured

Please let me know what I'm missing here and how to get search result based on metadata

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You really don't want to use `:` in your field names - these will break stuff in subtle ways and will have to be escaped everywhere (if they'll even work). Use `_`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try but I do not think this is an issue with ":" because i can get result with another node type nt:unstructured......somewhere I'm missing in AEM side

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Apache Jackrabbit Oak Solr Query index provider configuration in the felix console and enable the query time aggregation.

Comment: Hi Kunwar, you may consider follow the hints from here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." :)